# why my list not updated after get value from textfield flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have function to update the note by id in my list, but if i change the value, the list of map never updated

```
addNoteItem(String id, String val) {
    List<Map<String, String>> counterNoteItemList = _counterNoteItem.value;

    counterNoteItemList
        .where((test) => test.keys.toList()[0] == id)
        .toList()[0]
        .values
        .toList()[0] = val;

    print(
        "counterNoteItemList : ${counterNoteItemList.where((test) => test.keys.toList()[0] == id).toList()[0]} ");

    _counterNoteItem.sink.add(counterNoteItemList);
  }
```

this is my widget code, i use textfield and add onchange button to call my function in bloc and update then the stream, but when i print the stream its never updated

```
    Widget buildTextFieldNote(LaundryItems data, int index, int item) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Map<String, String>>>(
        stream: _crBloc.counterNoteItem,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                  inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: constants.customColors.borderColor)),
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: constants.customColors.borderColor)),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: constants.customColors.borderColor)))),
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                onChanged: (text) {

                  _crBloc.addNoteItem(
                      data.data.values.toList()[index][item].id, text);
                },
                maxLength: null,
                maxLines: null,

              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

I have found a solution, but I still feel weird, I think there is a better solution than this,
so I have a List that contains the `Map<String, String>,` when I want to make an update on a particular list so for example the contents of my list like this

```
  [
    "12ab" : "i love u",
    "22ab" : "i want u",
    "33ab" : "i need u"
   ]
```

, and I want to update the value for id 12ab to "i love u so much",
what I do now is find an object with key 12ab and then delete that object from the list, and add it with the new `Map<String, String>`

```
addNoteItem(String id, String val) {
    try {
      List<Map<String, String>> counterNoteItemList = _counterNoteItem.value;

      bool a = counterNoteItemList.remove(counterNoteItemList
          .where((test) => test.keys.toList()[0] == id)
          .toList()[0]);

      Map<String, String> temp = {id: val};
      counterNoteItemList.add(temp);

      _counterNoteItem.sink.add(counterNoteItemList);
    } catch (err) {}
  }
```

Comment: Can't see much going wrong in the above code. Can you plz also post widget code for stream builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setState(() {}) in class  satefull  extend StatefulWidget

and add class body extend state

void Getpost() {

```
  var url = "http://test/shop/";
  http.get(url).then((res) {
    dynamic list=convert.jsonDecode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
        {
          Datmodel_shop dp=new Datmodel_shop();
          dp.id=list[i]['id'];
          dp.title=list[i]['title'];
          dp.imageurl=list[i]['imageurl'];
          dp.date=list[i]['date'];
          dp.des=list[i]['des'];
          dp.price=list[i]['price'];
          dp.view=list[i]['view'];
          listproduct.add(dp);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just Add

```
setState(() {});
```

at the end of Function like

```
addNoteItem(String id, String val) {
List<Map<String, String>> counterNoteItemList = _counterNoteItem.value;

counterNoteItemList
    .where((test) => test.keys.toList()[0] == id)
    .toList()[0]
    .values
    .toList()[0] = val;

print(
    "counterNoteItemList : ${counterNoteItemList.where((test) => test.keys.toList()[0] == id).toList()[0]} ");

_counterNoteItem.sink.add(counterNoteItemList);

setState(() {}); // Updates the Wigdet

}
```